# deleting specific post in database(by post node) but it deletes entire database_table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete specific node in customer table using post id.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query applesQuery = ref.child("customers").orderByChild("post").equalTo(postid);
            applesQuery.getRef().removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

But it deletes all database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason all nodes get deleted is in this line:

```
applesQuery.getRef().removeValue();
```

The `Query.getRef()` call returns the location that this query runs on. Since `applesQuery` is a query on `post`, `applesQuery.getRef()` returns the `post` node itself. So `applesQuery.getRef().removeValue()` removes the entire `post` node.

There is no concept of a "delete query" in Firebase, where you send `DELETE FROM customer WHERE post = postid`. Firebase can only delete a node when it knows its exact path. This means that you will need to execute the query, loop through its results and delete each of those.

In code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query applesQuery = ref.child("customers").orderByChild("post").equalTo(postid);
applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue()
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

**Update**: I now noticed that the value of the `post` property is the same as what you have as the key for the customer. If that is always the case you don't need a query to delete the node, and can just do:

```
ref.child("customers").child(postid).removeValue();
```

Comment: Sir,sorry i mentioned wrong que..the actual is want to delete post by using post node in the table instead it deletes all post (n numbers of post are deleted if i want to delete specific post ).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the code I shared does. If it doesn't work for you, edit your queston to show what you did with the code from my answer. Also note that I added a simpler version, since based on the JSON you showed you might not need a query.

Comment: By using your updated code...it giving error( java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child())

Comment: That means `postid` is `null`.